# Unity can't build game for android

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wanted to try if I can build a game for android. I created a new project and switch to Android platform.
Installed all ndk,sdk.(automatically and manually. I tried both). But I can't build. When click create, nothings happen.

[Screenshoot](https://ibb.co/wgvSJD5)

Comment: Looks like something happened to me. Its asking you to either pick a folder or name your apk.

Answer (score 1):

Did you give the apk a name?
Nothing happens, what do you mean, the window closes and nothing further?
And yes, if you use a device, then you have to give Build and Run

Comment: In videos I watched before, they can click save button. But I can't. When I try nothing happens. I can click save button thousand times. It changes nothing

Comment: And you don't see any errors in the console?

Comment: No, not at all.